# HTML5 window.applicationCache - user decides to download

Tags: html

In HTML caching, my understanding is that when the manifest file is updated on the server, the browser downloads the latest files and swaps the cache.

Is there a way to stop the browser doing this until the user gives the go-ahead?

For example, displaying a notification to the user saying something like "there is a new version available. Do you want to download it? Y/N". If the user says "No", then the browser should keep the old files around.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [`updateready` event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#event-appcache-updateready) and then conditionally [call `swapCache()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#dom-appcache-swapcache).

Comment: I tried that. It seems the browser calls swapCache anyway. I tested it by changing the HTML. I handle the updateready event and I DON'T call swapCache(). When I modify the manifest file and reload the page, the new HTML appears even though I didn't call swapCache().

Comment: @knowledgequester Please add to your question the code you're using to handle `updateready`